# Как настроить TortoiseHg для работы с SVN?

Tags: linux, svn

Не знаю, как настраивать TortoiseHg для работы с SVN. Как настроить так, чтобы были видны файлы в ревизии?

Comment: Насколько я помню, TortoliseHg нужен для меркуриала, а для svn нужен TortoliseSVN. И раз уж Вы в линксе, пользуйтесь консолькой. На порядок удобнее!

Comment: Вот что за глупости, я бы посмотрел как вы мержи в консоле проводите. При активном тимворке только визуализация и спасает

Comment: по сабжу всё верно - TortoliseSVN, но если есть возможность - переходите на mercurial, он лучше на порядок. У вас уже и TortoiseHG стоит ;)

Comment: или на git, он ничем не хуже mercurial-а

Comment: _как вы мержи в консоле проводите._

а  я работаю в гите и придерживаюсь "ветка для маленькой фичи - пара мелких коммитов и назад в мастер". И если кофликты и бывают, то только по недосмотру. За последние полтора года было всего пару мелких.

Answer (score 1):

Никак. TortoiseHg используется для работы с Mercurial-репозиториями. 
Для работы с svn-репозиториями на Windows чаще всего используют TouroiseSvn, но его нет для Linux.

Поэтому вам надо либо работать с svn из консоли, либо подыскать другой gui-клиент, [например](http://rabbitvcs.org/).